# dojo.cookie across multiple pages?

Tags: dojo

I'm using dojo.cookie to store and retrieve cookie values. It works great on a single page. However, if I store a cookie on one page and try to retrieve it on another (still within the same website), it returns null. Is there a way to share a cookie across multiple pages within a website? I'm not sure if this is a dojo.cookie issue or a browser/cookie issue.

Comment: What does the call to `dojo.cookie` look like when you set the value?

Comment: dojo.cookie("IPAddress", IPAddress, { expires: 30 });

Comment: For the third arg, you might want to experiment with the `domain` and\or `path` properties to see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Yeah I tried putting "/" for the path and "localhost" for the domain but didn't have any success with either or both. Do I need to somehow pass those parameters in when I'm getting the cookie value as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I seem to recall issues with cookies and localhost, you might try adding an entry to `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 my.localhost.com
```

and then set the cookie as in your first comment but, when you hit the page, use `http://my.localhost.com` instead of `http://localhost`.